# What are some disadvantages of ubuntu GUI?

Tags: command-line, gui

Based on my personal experience GUI uses more computer memory (as the aim is to make it for user friendly and not resource optimized). As a result it can be slow, GUI becomes more complex if you need to communicate with the computer directly.
What are some disadvantages of ubuntu GUI?
can we have an official ubuntu CLI release?

Comment: Voting to close, since there is no actual question or problem here. Your question is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: There are different Ubuntu flavors to coose from. Some with leightweight desktop managers like LxQt (lubuntu) or XFCE (xubuntu). For a CLI install you could use the server ISO but I don't know what different packages get installed there.

Comment: This type of discussion would be better suited on the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/), which is a discussion site and not a Q&A site like Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @mawa GUI packages are downloaded again. for example [Humanity_Icons](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Artwork/Incoming/Karmic/Humanity_Icons)

Comment: @Artur Meinild I need a pure version. No photos, emoticons and clowns...etc.
The question is not based on personal opinion. I said this is my opinion and why I am looking for **a Professional, Official and Reproducible Ubuntu CLI release**.

Comment: Yes, and this question is closed, but you already have an answer - Ubuntu server (which is very well documented on the [Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation)).

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi right malicious ubuntu is not even reproducible, like malware tries to trick you.

Answer (score 3):

*Can we have an official ubuntu CLI release?*

We have an official CLI release, it is called [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server). Choose the manual server installation option.

Here are the [official instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-server#1-overview) for installing it.

*What are some disadvantages of ubuntu GUI?*

You pointed that out in your question. What exactly is your question, then?

Comment: I wanted to see what others think about GUI and how they came to live with its disadvantages.